# Override translation file django

Tags: python, html, django, translate, django-allauth

I'm actually coding a web app with django and just started to use django allauth to go a bit quicker in the creation of my user interface.

I've successfully changed the design of the templates by adding the templates from their github repo to my project. But I wanted to do the same with the translation because I want my app to be in french.

So I did the same : I added the "locale" folder to my project and edited some things in the .po files but no change happened.

Does someone know what to do, like what more is needed to override the ancient traductions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Overriteing code is not quicker way. In Django package allauth You got evrything you need. Read documantation:
https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

But if you really wanna overrite code i dont recommend to copy all of file code from library. You can Simly overrite 1 function / class. If you will do that and pass diffrent arguments you get diffrent return sounds siple. **But for reall Overrite code for me is hard option that you should do only when its need**
Simple way how to overrite code:

```
class cl():
name = "Mephju"
def function(self, arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2, self.name)

class overrite_cl():
    name = "Mephju"
    def function(self, arg1, arg2):
        print(arg1, self.name)

print(overrite_cl)
```

This is bad example how to make it but i wanna make you understand. While Overriteing you pass same class parrent and then type function you wanna overrite.

Ok now my code example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnW3L.png)
**This is from library**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i5ac.png)

red lines is thing that i changed. So as you can see This is same function but with diffrent return. I'm still returning this to same algorythm. But now its return something diffrent.

*I dont know what are you trying to make in your web app but i'm shure thing you wanna make its allredy in django allauth.*

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply ! May be I've not been clear enough but what I want is just to add new translations / modify translations in the corresponding .po files. Indeed, it is not that django allauth does not have features I need, it is just that I need to customize it (as I have customised templates).